# Two similar spans with onclick event, one not working?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

Running into a very strange problem, and for the life of me I can't find out why this isn't working:

js:

```
function Test()
{
  alert("test");
}
```

html:

```
<span id='bla' onclick='Test()'>
  Click me
</span>

<hr>

<span id='bla2' onclick='alert("test2")'>
  Click me too
</span>
```

Live demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/gc4533qz/

Why does clicking on the 2nd line generate a popup, **but clicking on the first does not?**

Comment: In jsfiddle you should set `Load type` to `No wrap` if you have event attribute in your html. Check https://jsfiddle.net/gc4533qz/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is a result of one of the default settings in JSFiddle.

You'll need to change one of the javascript settings.

Change the LOAD TYPE setting from:

[image]

to:

[image]

And that should do the trick!